# Uri.TryCreate - error - Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, uri, indexoutofboundsexception

I can't make sense of this error. My application is 64 bit, i have 32 gb ram memory and software not even using 1 gb ram when this error happened.

So what may cause this error and how to solve ? C# 5

[image]

Here the stacktrace

```
   at System.Uri.EscapeUnescapeIri(Char* pInput, Int32 start, Int32 end, UriComponents component)
   at System.Uri.EscapeUnescapeIri(String input, Int32 start, Int32 end, UriComponents component)
   at System.Uri.ParseRemaining()
   at System.Uri.InitializeUri(ParsingError err, UriKind uriKind, UriFormatException& e)
   at System.Uri.CreateHelper(String uriString, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind, UriFormatException& e)
   at System.Uri.TryCreate(String uriString, UriKind uriKind, Uri& result)
```

Comment: What is the value of `srUrl`?

Comment: It is just string. please check here for url : http://pastebin.com/xA9Y5fVq . Edit After you mentioned it contains very weird characters actually :D

Comment: I feel dirty for copy/pasting that Uri, but a quick test in LINQPad for .NET 4.0 worked fine. Don't have .NET 4.5 at the moment to test with unfortunately.

Comment: So @ChrisSinclair i suppose it is not related to string itself ?

Comment: Perhaps not. Try having your project build/target a lower .NET version. (probably try 3.5 or lower as the 4.5 in-place installation probably affects a 4.0 build as well)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair did you try the url inside of pastebin page ? you tried just the pastebin url :D

Comment: Yes, I copy/pasted the crazy url to the... questionable content. EDIT: Perhaps something was lost in translation between pasting to pastebin, displaying in the browser, and copy/paste again.